# How do I get velocity for my character in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

im trying to make a teleporter game and my character needs to have some velocity and gravity, does anyone know what sums i need to be able to acomplish this?

This is my code so far:

```
var char = this.addChild(new Char());
char.width = 20;
char.height = 20;
char.x = startPos.x;  //startPos is an invisible movieclip that I can move around to     make the starting position
char.y = startPos.y;        // accurate
var vx:Number = 0;
var vt:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler (e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch (e.keyCode)  {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        char.y = char.y - 5   
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really help with your question, but it's just a suggestion: you could make `startPos` a `Point` instead of a `MovieClip`. It has `x` and `y` properties so you can still use it the same as usual, but it's simpler and may improve performance slightly (since Flash Player doesn't have to worry about whether it should draw it or not).

Comment: Go to [flashAndMath.com](http://www.flashandmath.com) and check out the tutorials there. They have ones on this and all sorts of other things you'll need to know to build games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your char only needs to go up then the following code will do the job.

But if it needs to move in all direction then much advanced code is required. 
Follow [Moving Character in all directions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844565/having-trouble-moving-a-character-in-as3/5844754#5844754)

This is a quick solution to your need.

```
var gravity:Number = 2;

var velocity:Number = 1.1;

var move:Boolean = false;

function moveChar(e:Event):void
{
   if(move)
   {
       gravity *= velocity; 
       char.y -= gravity; // move char
   }
}
char.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar, false, 0, true);


//Keyboard events
function keyDownHandler (e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (e.keyCode) 
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        move = true;
    }
}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyUpHandler (e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    move = false;
    gravity = 2;
}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
```

Comment: I need to make it move in all directions, and also can you make it slow down once the key has been released?

Comment: @samtheman999 I have added a link in my answer. Please refer it.